# Woman goes to jail and a student helps her learn to read

Tags: identify-this-movie

Over 10 years ago or even more, I saw a movie in the TV. I have been searching for the past week for the title but to no success. Consequently, I thought I might find here some help.

Since I have seen it only once and a long time ago, I do not remember most of the details (like the title, etc.), but I will try to give a detailed description to everything I can recall.

The movie is old, I don't know how many years old, but as I said I have seen it 10 years ago in a television in Albania, so I guess it should be at least 13 years old. I have seen it in English (I don't believe it was dubbed).

Scenes I remember:

- There was a young boy who was caught in a bad rain and got sick. He was standing next to a door(or stairs) under a roof and an old lady sees him and takes him home. She lived in the house where the door(or the stairs) led, the one where the boy was standing.
- After he gets better, he leaves the house. In another scene, he returns in the some house with some flowers in his hand to thank the old women. There she tells him to take a shower. He does and when he is done, she goes behind naked and there they have sex.
- In all the scenes that followed that they had sex, she always used to ask him to read a book for her because she could not read.
- In a scene, they go on holidays riding bikes and they stop for lunch in a restaurant and the waiter thinks the old woman is his mother and to tell the waiter the truth, he kisses her in front of him.
- She used to work somewhere (I don't remember what job), and her colleagues put a building on fire and manage to blame her because she could not read and was to proud to admit she could not read & write. No one knew she never learnt how to read and write.
- In the court, the once young boy, but now a law student, was in the court watching how a court session goes. He makes all the connections that the accused woman was the one he used to sleep with when he was young.
- In jail, the woman learns how to read and write by hearing the tapes the boy sent her and by trying to read the books that came together with the tapes.

That's all I remember. Anyone has any idea what the title of the movie is?

Comment: That kind of details we always expect in an Identify-this-X questions. Therefore +1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for [The Reader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Reader_(2008_film)).

> The Reader is a 2008 German-American romantic drama film directed by Stephen Daldry and written by David Hare, based on the 1995 German novel of the same name by Bernhard Schlink. Ralph Fiennes and Kate Winslet star along with the young actor David Kross.
>
> Berlin in 1995. Michael Berg watches an U-Bahn pass by—then flashing back to a tram in 1958 Neustadt. A 15-year-old Michael (David Kross) gets off because he feels sick and wanders the streets, pausing in the entryway of a nearby apartment building where he vomits. Hanna Schmitz (Kate Winslet), a tram conductor, comes in and helps him return home.
> Michael, diagnosed with scarlet fever, rests at home for the next three months. After he recovers, he visits Hanna with flowers to thank her. The 36-year-old Hanna seduces him and they begin an affair. They spend much of their time together having sex in her apartment after she has had Michael read to her from literary works he is studying. After a bicycling trip, Hanna learns she is being promoted to a clerical job at the tram company. She abruptly moves without telling Michael.

Rest of the plots unfold as you described.

Here is the trailer of the movie.